# How to make a div scrollable when it overflows by adding children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following div:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-4 ticker">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="lol()">sdas</button>
```

I append children to that by jQuery.

```
<script>
function lol()  {

    $( ".ticker" ).append( "<p>dsadsa</p>" );
}
</script>
```

I want when the are more children than can fit on the div max-height the div to become scrollable, any help how can I achieve that?

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=RuintOf6bR

Comment: css, .ticker {  overflow-y:scroll } maybe?

Comment: @tgeery I thought that overflow:scroll is the default value, and you have to set it to hidden in the opposite case.

Comment: default is visible... http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: use `overflow:auto` to have the scrollbar show only when it has reason to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.ticker{
    height: 700px;
    max-height: 700px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: As suggested in comments above, `overflow-y: auto` is a better choice; `scroll` will cause scrollbars to appear even when not necessary.